# Github Readme.md Color Box

Tags: github, colors, github-api, colorbox, github-flavored-markdown

I want to add a color box to the *README.md* in my GitHub repository

In the beginning, the below worked:

```
![#243B55](https://via.placeholder.com/10/243B55?text=+) #243B55
```

But after the new API, the below works for some colors but not for all:

```
![#f03c15](https://via.placeholder.com/15/f03c15/f03c15.png) `#f03c15`
```

How can get a code for all colors?

Comment: That second link works just fine for me. What problem are you seeing?

Comment: Not showing some colors and only showing the default image icon